# Ubuntu Mate For Rpi2 default resolution can't be changed

Tags: display, hdmi, mate, display-resolution, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu Mate 15.04 on my brand new RPI2 and the default resolution in the HDMI port is very small and can't be changed using system default display window. But when I play video using OMXPLAYER it plays it on the whole screen with the correct resolution.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

maybe you're experiencing the default setting for the overscan.

try uncommenting

```
disable_overscan=1
```

in /boot/config.txt (or /boot/firmware/config.txt on some distros) by removing the # and save (as root)

[here](http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/28/raspi-display-setting.html)'s a more detailed description.

EDIT:

[man](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video)page

Comment: glad i could help :)

Comment: In my case, the file is /boot/config.txt (ubuntu-mate-15.10.1-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi-2).

Comment: The referenced description also says /boot/config.txt, please update the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I think this should help you and all **rasbperry pi users** (no modification to any text files is necessary), I ran into the same problem, where the default was 640x480 resolution, the monitor was unknown and I ended up using xrandr at first and all the other stuff which didn't work. But I realized that ubuntu mate like raspbian does have **raspi-config** available so you can do is go into the mate terminal then type

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then you can choose **advanced settings** then **Resolution**, you should be able to select **optimal resolution settings**. After rebooting the changes should take affect. Well for me I chose the 1920x1080 and oddly enough when I checked the display settings it wasn't monitor: unknown anymore but my samsung monitor this time was recognized, you can view it  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNdSP.jpg), which allowed me to choose from lots of resolutions so I hope this helps the readers too.

Answer (score 1):

I made it.
Open Terminal. Run the commands:

```
<user>: - $ sudo nano /boot/config.txt///disable_overscan=1
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

And

```
<user>: - $ sudo raspi-config and reset overscan (/// Advanced // Overscan // Yes)
```

And Restart

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu Server 64-bit on RP4 the file you should edit is `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`